# How to check apache2 error logs at Github Actions failure?

Tags: github-actions, wget, http-status-code-500

Our github actions pipeline suddenly started to fail this morning and we're not sure why. We always tested the setup with a simple `wget localhost`, which now returns 500. Is there a way to reach or dump the apache error log to get more details?

```
    --2022-12-12 11:18:43--  http://localhost/
    Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
    Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
    2022-12-12 11:18:43 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Link to test run: https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/actions/runs/3675217376/jobs/6214370211

We're using the Ubuntu 18.04 image. Switching to Ubuntu 20.04 seems to break the connection to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the now deprecated github actions docker image for ubuntu 18.04. I will try to update to ubuntu-latest instead.